# Javascript Populate HTML hidden input with JSON and quote issue when sent to server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

Hello I have the following JSON and I'm using Javascript to populate a hidden input with it:

```
$("#myHiddenInput").val(data);

var data =   
   [
      {
        "id":"522",
        "description":"Whitesands Bay"
      },
      { 
        "id":"590",
        "description":"Eastbourne Beachy Head"
      }
    ]
```

The issue is that in my HTML page the code for that input field looks like :

```
<input id="_myHiddenInput" type="hidden" name="myHiddenInput" value="[{"id":"522","description":"Whitesands Bay"},{"id":"590","description":"Eastbourne Beachy Head"}]">
```

and this is not valid HTML, it has to be single quotes in `value='"...JSON....."'` because when I submit the form to PHP that has that field I get no result from PHP. Seems like the browser is always forcing the value attribut to start with double quotes like this `value=""...JSON... ""`

How can I fix that please?

Comment: You should pass each value with different input hidden tag. that is the better way to access your data from server side

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against passing the entire object into a single hidden field. You should store each item in the object as a unique hidden field, which will be serialized when you submit the form.

```
var data = {
    "id": "522",
    "description": "Whitesands Bay"
}, {
    "id": "590",
    "description": "Eastbourne Beachy Head"
}];

$.each(data, function (i) {
    $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i]['id'] + '" /><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="'+data[i]['description']+'" />');
});
```

The `name="id[]"` or `name="description[]"` syntax tells PHP to serialize the values of the array of hidden inputs. If the form is submitted with the `GET` method, the serialized values of ID and description will be stored in an array in the global variables `$_GET['id']` and `$_GET['description']` respectively.

I have [created a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/4aeEz/) with a twist - the hidden inputs are changed to text so you can visualize how the hidden fields would have been added to the form.

I would also like to offer a friendly (and less cumbersome) suggestion: that if the ID and description are both fetched from the database, you might simply want to return the ID itself, and then let the PHP script that is executed upon form submission to retrieve the description. That saves you a lot of work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but my problem is that I have to pas it as JSON to PHP because I'm decoding it and generation a PDF from it so I can't split it into many inputs moreover that JSON is in reality more bigger than that It could have 1000 block "id,description" so I do'nt want to have 1000 inputs in my form.

Comment: the only issue is that double quotes in the value attribute.

Comment: Here is what I did and the issue was fixed, I don't know if it's a good solution but it works. In Javascript I escaped my double quotes like this :`$("#hidden_SearchResult_input").val(gJsonData.replace(/(^|[^\\])"/g, '$1\\"'));` and in PHP I removed that escaping thing with : `$jsonDataAdjusted = str_replace("\\\\\\", "", $_POST['hidden_SearchResult_input']);` What do you think?